# I am getting the following error while executing my code : com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5

Tags: android, xdebug, leakcanary

I am getting the following error while executing my code.

> Error: Could not find method debugdcompile() for arguments 
>   [com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5] on object of type 
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in app.gradle

```
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
```

Add `mavenCentral()` along with `jcenter` and  to **allprojects** section in **build.gradle** .

That May Help in fixing the Issue.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `debugdcompile`, which is wrong. It is supposed to be `debugCompile`. The C has to be capitalized and the `d` isn't even supposed to be in there

Comment: Actually, he even wrote `debugdcompile`, with the d typo